# For loop accessing two iteration positions in an array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
someList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for i,j in enumerate(someList) step 2:
    print('%s, %s' % (someList[i], someList[i+1]))
```

My question is, is there any way to simplify the iteration over the array in order to avoid the `enumerate` part and still accessing two variables at a time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for x, y in zip(someList, someList[1:]):
    print x, y
```

Standard technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two iterators, call next on the second and then zip which avoids the need to  copy the list elements by slicing:

```
someList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

it1, it2 = iter(someList),  iter(someList)
next(it2)

for a,b in zip(it1,  it2):
   print(a, b)
```